# How to get LineItems of an Order using Shopware 6 Store API

Tags: api, integration, shopware, shopware6

I want to integrate shopware in my application and I have a problem with the api.

I used dockware.io solution to get started with shopware and create a demo store. I was able to create customers and products and place orders.

But while I request the order through the API, I am not able to get lineItems of the order, it is always null. I have the same problem with the deliveries attribute. Here is a screenshot of the response to my request.

[image]

Why am I not receiving the items in the reply? Is there any other request I can make to receive them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `lineItems` association in the request body of your API request. Same for the `deliveries` association and so on.

```json
{
    "associations": {
        "lineItems": [],
        "deliveries": []
    }
}
```

Comment: It works good for POST. Is it possible for GET?